# I want To make a sphere of hexagon with sverchok but have some issues

Tags: sverchok

I want to make a sphere of hexagon (like on photo #1) with [Sverchok](https://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/) (blender 2.93) but have some issues. Hexagons of my sphere (photo #2) are not rotated correctly. How can I rotate them, and create sphere of hexagons like on photo #1? thanks.

[image: correct and hexagon rotation]

[image: Node group]

Comment: is this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaio1.png ok or does it have to be all hexagons?

Comment: .. Hexagons don't tessellate a sphere.. so if you want a tessellation, it's a geodesic dome, with pentagonal insertions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a completely even tesselation, you won't manage with hexagons. You can see here a best case but it includes pentagons as well:
[image]

Otherwise you can wrap a polygon grid or, in this case a brick grid with toothing so the wrap joins up correctly at the back, around a NURBS sphere. This will result in pinching towards the poles.
[image]